# session id shows as undefined node.js

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, redis, socket.io

js, express, redis (for memory store), and socket.io. I am trying to setup authenticated socket calls to match sockets with each user. I have this code that does it for the most part except for some reason the sessionID shows as undefined and getting error loading session (handshake error).

Here is the code:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var notificationsN = io.listen(server);
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
var redis = require("redis").createClient();
var cookie = require('cookie');
var session_store = new RedisStore({client: redis});

app.use(express.session({
      secret: "secret",
      store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 3000, client: redis })
  }));
notificationsN.configure(function() {
  notificationsN.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {

    console.log('data below');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('data sid below');
    console.log(data.sessionID);
    if(!data.headers.cookie ) return accept( new Error('No user cookie found'), true );
      data.cookie = cookie.parse( data.headers.cookie, { secure: true } );
      data.cookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies( data.cookie, config.session.secret );
      data.cookie = connect.utils.parseJSONCookies( data.cookie );
      data.sessionID = data.cookie[config.session.key];
      session_store.load( data.sessionID, function( err, session ){
        if( err || !session ) return accept( new Error('Error loading session'), false );
        data.session = session;
        return accept( null, true );
      });
      console.log(data);

  })
})


notificationsN.on('connection', function(socket) {
 socket.on('message', function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('disconnecting from redis');

    });

  });
```

Here is what I get back from `console.log(data)`:

```
{ headers:
   { host: 'localhost:3000',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTM
L, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36',
     accept: '*/*',
     referer: 'http://localhost:3000/userProfile',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
     cookie: 'connect.sid=crazyvalue; __atuvc=crazyvalue; userid=crazyvalue' },
  address: { address: 'ip', port: port},
  time: 'Fri Aug 30 2013 15:50:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  query: { t: '1377892231624' },
  url: '/socket.io/1/?t=1377892231624',
  xdomain: false,
  secure: undefined,
  issued: 1377892231630,
  cookie: {},
  sessionID: undefined }
```

So not sure why sessionID is undefined and secure shows as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_store.load
```

Is asynchronous.  You need to move your console.log into the callback of this function.

```
session_store.load( data.sessionID, function( err, session ){
    if( err || !session ) return accept( new Error('Error loading session'), false );
    data.session = session;
    console.log(data);//Move it here.
    return accept( null, true ); //This return statement is doing nothing useful
});
```

Comment: I did that, but it still printing out the same values of undefined

Comment: At the very least this was problematic so I'd still leave it.  You seem to be changing around data.cookie a lot.  What do calls to JSON.stringify(data.cookie, 0, 4) get you for each step?

Comment: The first time I am calling cookie.parse (it shows up the cookie) but then after that it is just showing as {}

Comment: Well then it would appear one of the calls you're doing in there isn't working.  The first time you see {}, you have an empty object.  The call before that didn't work.

Comment: data.cookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies( data.cookie, config.session.secret ); Apparently it is that line then? Not sure what is wrong with that though?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to even begin answering why that line would be messing up.  If you're getting a JSON object from the original cookie data, I'd suggest just using that sessionID, unless you need it parsed further for some reason...

Comment: Well the cookie is still there but I need to actually assign the sessionID which is not working for some reason that is the problem I am having, because even after that first data.cookie call I am still getting session as undefined when I am setting data.sessionID =